# Circumference touching a sine wave

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, analytic-geometry

I'm trying to get the intersection points between a sine function and a circumference.
So, i have this equations:

$y = a\sin(bx + c) + d$
$(x-h)^2 + (y-k)^2 = r^2$

If i substitute the sine in the second equation i have this:

$(x-h)^2 + (a\sin(bx + c) + d-k)^2 = r^2$

In other case, developing the quadratics and ordering the $x$'s to the left should be enough, but having trigonometric functions is a problem because they aren't in $x$ terms really

$x^2 - 2xh + h^2 + a^2\sin^2(bx+c) + 2a\sin(bx+c)\cdot\ (d-k)+(d-k)^2 = r^2$

I just need to get the solutions of the system, i don't know what to do at this point. Any help would be grateful

Comment: I am afraid that you will not get any analytical solution. Remember that this is already the case for $x=\cos(x)$.

Comment: HINT Wlog consider t=bx+c;x=h+r cos t;y=k+rsint; No analytical solution is possible. Numerical solution by visualized graphic works best for particular cases.